# How to read an unsigned double value from ByteBuffer

Tags: java, unsigned, bytebuffer

I am facing a problem regarding unsigned values in java. Can any please me please.
Actually the problem is, I am having a bytebuffer in which different data types are placed ( eg- 1st a float then a double and then an int after that double like wise) and some of them may be signed and some are unsigned. I am having the list having their order and data type and sign information so i am reading them from the bytebuffer and directly assigning them to the corresponding variables

Eg:

```
int i= bytebuffer.getInt();
```

Every thing is fine but for the unsigned max values it is giving as negative value. For int float, double this is the same issue I am facing.

I read some where that the java wont support unsigned values but i came across the convertions of int , short into unsigned values but I could not able to find about the double, float.

EDIT:
 My code is

```
        File file= new File("blob_960");
        int count,length;

        length = (int)(file.length());
        count=(length/380);

         ByteBuffer bytebufr= ByteBuffer.allocate(length);

        bytebufr.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

        byte[] bytes= new byte[length];

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

        fis.read(bytes,0, length);

        bytebufr.put(bytes);
        bytebufr.position(0);

                    int i = bytebufr.getInt();
                    float f = bytebufr.getFloat();
                    double d = bytebufr.getDouble();
```

example - byte value is there 220 
I am reading the byte using

```
            byte b = bytebufr.get();
            System.out.println(b); // this is giving -36 
           // I am expecting 220.

    Binary value of 220 is -11011100
    Binary value of -36 is -11011100
```

It is considering the value as signed value and giving -36 but the value is unsigned and I am expecting 220.

The same with the double also.

Any body please help on this.

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Unsigned integer---I've heard of that. But unsigned double? That's a first.

Comment: What does not work with `getDouble()`? What do you get, and what do you expect?

Comment: Yes.. we are having unsigned doubles. Here I am getting the double from the byte buffer if it is the MAX Double then it is reading as negative value from the byte buffer.

Comment: Unsigned doubles are not specified by the IEEE standard, so whatever you have, it's nonstandard hence unsupported in JDK or any other standard library.

Comment: Are you sure that the file contains the proper data? Is the endinaness correct? Can you provide a source-code only example which writes the relevant data into the buffer (e.g. using an array) without reading it from a file so that we are able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: There is no such thing as unsigned floating point (double in this case)

Comment: What I am doing is the correct way because I am getting all the values except the values having MSB as 1( these values are taking as signed though few are unsigned..

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Java has only signed values (except of char, which might be seen as an unsigned short).

For unsigned short (for instance) one can read/write a short, and hold its value in a (signed) int:

```
short x = -3; // But intended as unsigned 0xFFFD
int ux = x & 0xFFFF; // The unsigned value by masking
```

And so on.

Unsigned double I am hearing the first time. Check the binary format.
For signed java double, there is a sign bit, which probably for unsigned double adds to the mantisse. In that case with a slight loss of a precision a conversion should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

How binary data is interpreted is solely up to you - if you want 8bit value to be treated/printed as unsigned (in java) just cast it to longer value removing extra bits that may appear due to sign extension - for example like that:

```
byte b = (byte) 0xFF;
int i = ((int)b) & 0xff;
System.out.println("b=[" + b + "]   b interpreted as unsigned is = [" + i + "]");
```

yields:

> b=[-1]   b interpreted as unsigned is = [255]

just a matter of interpretation - just read integer vars as they are but for printing as unsigned values perform operations similar to these above.

Of course this aplies to integer types here and not to floating points as they are always signed. If you want them positive use abs etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can read signed/unsigned integers of arbitrary length with the help of `BigInteger`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final byte FULL_BYTE = (byte) 0xFF;
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[] { FULL_BYTE, FULL_BYTE, FULL_BYTE, FULL_BYTE });
    System.out.println(readSignedInteger(buffer, 4, true)); // => -1
    buffer.rewind();
    System.out.println(readUnsignedInteger(buffer, 4, true)); // => 4294967295
    buffer.rewind();
    System.out.println(readSignedInteger(buffer, 2, true)); // => -1
    buffer.rewind();
    System.out.println(readUnsignedInteger(buffer, 2, true)); // => 65535
}

public static BigInteger readUnsignedInteger(ByteBuffer buffer, int length, boolean littleEndian) {
    return new BigInteger(1, readBytes(buffer, length, littleEndian));
}

public static BigInteger readSignedInteger(ByteBuffer buffer, int length, boolean littleEndian) {
    return new BigInteger(readBytes(buffer, length, littleEndian));
}

public static byte[] readBytes(ByteBuffer buffer, int length, boolean reversed) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        bytes[reversed ? length - 1 - i : i] = buffer.get();
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

You can convert `BigInteger` to primitive types via `byteValue`, `shortValue`, `intValue`, `longValue` methods.

For the floating point types, you can do something very similar with `BigDecimal` and its `unscaledValue()` (i.e. mantissa).

Note that you won't be able to convert *unsigned long* and *unsigned double* to any corresponding primitive type (as there is none in Java).